# Skipping file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/. File does not exist

Tags: aws-cli, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a file in my root directory `catalog.json`. I use a bitbucket pipeline to perform this step:

```
 - aws s3 cp catalog.json s3://testunzipping/ --recursive
```

However, I get an error that:
`Skipping file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/catalog.json/. File does not exist.`

Why is it checking for the catalog.json file in this path? Why is not extracting the file from the root? How can I modify the command accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use `--recursive` for a single file. The command is trying to evaluate it as a directory because of the `--recursive` parameter. And it's ending up giving `File does not exist` error. I reproduced it by trying to copy a single file with `--recursive` parameter, I got the same error, but after removing it, it worked.

You can use this ;

`aws s3 cp catalog.json s3://testunzipping/`

Also for the answer of your other question;
Bitbucket Pipelines runners are using `/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build` directory. This is actually pipelines' root directory. Runners are pulling code from the repo there and processing it according to your pipeline structure. It's a built-in situation.